# Why do I have to set my displacement map strength so low?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, displacement

I'm finding my displacement maps displace my object by an inordinate amount, I've got some of them set to .0005 strength (most to .001) which is off the scale (although doable anyway) and I feel like this isn't right. I wouldn't worry about this normally except this project has to be done professionally and I'm worried I'm not doing it right

I've set my texture to use non-colour space and it was generated in X-Normal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a purely modifier based displacement, here are some pictures: https://imgur.com/a/5B1He

Comment: Is the object really really small? That could mean that the displacements have to be proportionally smaller too.

Comment: It tells "Can't load texture" which generally means Blender can't open the file. Hence all the displacement is made with black color (values of 0). Did you try to open the image and preview the displacement with the texture being accessible? Note also that Middle level which means no displacement is by default 0.5, probably that could change a bit

Comment: Oh my days that's it! Ha thankyou :D I can now fix the issue by changing the unit scale and scaling up everything :)

Comment: Yeah I've been messing with that middle level, helps with some thinner areas. As it turns out though it was all about the scale anyway ha. Thanks anyhow

Comment: Please read:[**Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

Comment: @cegaton Ack I used to be so good with doing this by routine XD Thanks